# Problen migrating .Net AES functions to Java

Tags: aes

We have encrypt/decrypt writen in .Net, but when migrate to java it give different results even using the same secret key pair and salt.

Pls help me how to fix java code? Thank you!

For example: Encrypt string "Hello world" in .Net give different result when encrypt that string in Java.

MY C# CODE

```
namespace Utils
{
    public class AES256Crypto
    {
        const string saltStr = "test";
        const string password = "test@1234";

        public static string EncryptString(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] baPwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

                // Hash the password with SHA256
                byte[] baPwdHash = SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(baPwd);

                byte[] baText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

                var baEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(baText, baPwdHash);

                string result = Convert.ToBase64String(baEncrypted);
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

   
        private static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.       
            byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltStr);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return encryptedBytes;
        }

    }
}
```

MY JAVA CODE

```
 public static String encrypt(String plainText) {

    try {
    String salt = "test";
    String password = test@1234";

    String initializationVector = "                ";



    int pswdIterations = 1000;

    int keySize = 256;



    byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");// "UTF-8");

    byte[] ivBytes = initializationVector.getBytes("UTF-8");// "UTF-8");



    // Derive the key, given password and salt.

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");// PBEWithMD5AndDES");

    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, pswdIterations, keySize);



    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);

    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");



    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); // Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCSPadding"

    

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));



    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));// UTF-8"));

    String str = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64().encodeAsString(encryptedTextBytes);



    return str;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return e.toString();
}
```

We have encrypt/decrypt writen in .Net, but when migrate to java it give different results even using the same secret key pair and salt.

Pls help me how to fix java code? Thank you!

Comment: You haven't explained a problem yet, and without that information it's impossible to help. Please [edit] your post to clearly explain the problem you're having, and ask a more specific question. You should read [ask] and [mre] first. Your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

Comment: I have added more description to the post. Thanks